# I am getting segmentation fault when removing a array that is unused, any ideas why?

Tags: c

I'm having some troubles with my code, whenever I remove the 2d array validEdges I get a segmentation
error even though I do not use the array anywhere in my code? Anyone have any idea why? Thank you very much for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int GraphMatrixSize;

    printf("Enter size of matrix/graph: ");
    scanf("%d", &GraphMatrixSize);

    int GraphMatrix[GraphMatrixSize][GraphMatrixSize];
    printf("Enter matrix line by line: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < GraphMatrixSize; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < GraphMatrixSize; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &GraphMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Order of traversal: 0 ");

    int validEdges[1000][1000];

    char c[200];

    int queue[200];
    int up = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <200; i++) {
        c[i] = 'W';
        }

    queue[0] = -1;
    queue[up] = 0;

    c[0] = 'G';

    int u;
    int counter = 0;
    int down = 0;
    while (counter < GraphMatrixSize) {
        u = queue[down];
        down++;
        for (int i = 0; i < GraphMatrixSize;i++) {
            if (GraphMatrix[i][i] == 1) {
                if (c[i] == 'W') {
                    c[i] = 'G';

                    printf("%d ",i);

                    up++;
                    queue[up] = i;
                }
            }
        c[u] = 'B';
      }
      counter++;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is unadvised to use stack allocated dynamic array, as you might easily have a issue allocating the array, causing a segfault

Comment: also `c` is 200 char long, what could be the maximum value for `GraphMatrixSize`

Comment: issue is with,  queue[0] = -1;down=0;u = queue[down];c[u] = 'B'; possibility of c[-1]

Answer (score -1):

`int GraphMatrix[GraphMatrixSize][GraphMatrixSize];` is an array allocated in stack memory. This means that the size of `int GraphMatrix[GraphMatrixSize][GraphMatrixSize];` must be know at compile time.
Because you get the value of `GraphMatrixSize` from user input (`scanf("%d", &GraphMatrixSize);`), the size of the array cannot be known at compile time.
If the compiler does not know the size of the array at compile-time, you need to dynamically allocate `GraphMatrix`, with the function `malloc` or allocate `GraphMatrix` to a sufficiently big matrix e.g. `int GraphMatrix[512][512];`.

Comment: Welcome to the year 1999, we now have variable length arrays. I'd advise to study what has happened in the C language since the previous millennium before attempting to teach it to others.